# Code block is not visible after using HTML <ul> (or "-" before text if you prefer)

Tags: support, markdown, list

When answering/asking a question if you want to achieve

- a black dot before the text,

you can either use "-" before your text or use:

```
<ul>
  <li>some text</li>
<ul/>
```

So far so good, but I just noticed that if I use this black dotted text, any code blocks will not be seen after.

Here I have two screenshots to better illustrate the problem:

---

**With "-" before the text:**

[image]

---

**And now without:**[image]

---

As you probably noticed, the code blocks are only seen if the "-" char does not exist.

Why is this happening? Is this a bug or something that I miss regarding this answer/question editor?

Comment: indent the code 4 more spaces or leave an extra blank line depending on whether you want the code to look like it's part of the list or not.

Comment: Markdown can get tricky sometimes. Code formatting inside list items is one of those times when it's tricky.